# Combinations with repetition in python, where order MATTERS

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics, cartesian-product

From python's Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

see combinations_with_replacement: "# combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2) --> AA AB AC BB BC CC"

I'd like to use the same function, with the bonus of generating "BA", "CA", and "CB".

Comment: So permutations instead of combinations?

Comment: Permutations won't return AA, BB, or CC.  Need `itertools.product('ABC', repeat=2)`.

Comment: "combinations allowing reordering" = permutations. "permutations with replacement" = cartesian product. Simple as.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`itertools.product` is definitely the method you're looking for here. As the documentation states, it is effectively a compact for loop; `product(A,B)` is equivalent to `((x, y) for x in A for y in B)`

`product` will return every combination of elements that it can, order-specific, so `product('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')` will get you `ADG, ADH, ADI, AEG [...] CFI`. If you want to include repetition, you set the optional `repeat` variable. `product(A, repeat=4)` is equivalent to `product(A,A,A,A)`. Similarly, `product(A, B, repeat=3)` is the same as `product(A,B,A,B,A,B)`.

In short: to get the result you're looking for, call `itertools.product('ABC', repeat=2)`. This will get you tuples `AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC`, in order.